# Starting Stencil - Localhost URL Never Loads

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm new to developing with Stencil, and I'm having a bit of trouble getting started.

After running:

```
stencil start
```

I get the startup information, and ASCII graphic loading in terminal, along with the localhost URLs which should allow me to view the frontend and work on the store. Whenever I visit the http://localhost:3000 URL, nothing ever loads.

It seems that something is in fact working, because when I edit and save a SCSS file, I get a terminal line recognizing that a file was changed.

I'm running on macOS High Sierra, v. 10.13.3

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling stencil-cli, along with the JS utilities a dozen times and also tried different versions of Node -- namely 4.4.0, 6.10.3, and 7.9.0

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot? I sat down with a coworker and ran through the setup on their machine and everything worked perfectly. This must be an isolated issue somehow to my machine, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there something different between your computer and your co-workers. When you say nothing loads, do you mean its just a blank screen? What browser are you using and are there any console errors?

Comment: Thanks for responding!

The difference between our computers should be minimal, it's the same hardware and most of the same software.

Nothing loads at all -- just a blank screen and no errors in the console. This is in Chrome. FirefoxDeveloperEdition immediately loads with a page not found error.

Comment: Hi Thad, looks like you asked this in our forum at BigCommerce. We can go ahead and continue the conversation there. Thanks!

Comment: @T.J. I actually just got my answer from the forum at BC. The following lines were completely ommited from my hosts file for some reason...

`127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was has been resolved. The following lines were completely missing from my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```